# Writing a secure REST web service

Tags: web-services, security, rest, hash, checksum

Many of them are getting confused on how to write a secure rest webservice, for those who are confused to which method to use this post will be helpful in a great way.

**Possible ways of writing REST services(Partially Secure)**

- You realize that literally passing the credentials over HTTP leaves that data open to being sniffed in plain-text; After the Gawker incident, you realize that plain-text or weakly-hashed anything is usually a bad idea.
- You realize that hashing the password and sending the hash over the wire in lieu of the plain-text password still gives people sniffing at least the username for the account and a hash of the password that could (in a disturbing number of cases) be looked up in a Rainbow Table.
- you exclaim, because in this case (which is really a username/password scenario all over again) you still suffer from the same problems (sniffed traffic) that sending the username and password in plain text had.
- At this point you are about to give up and concede to using **OAuth**, but you insist that there has to be a secure but relatively easy way to design a public web API that can keep credentials private.

Comment: Don't pass credentials over HTTP. Use HTTPS.

Comment: `Many of them`, who? And did only I miss the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Best Possible Solution**

A server and a client know a public and private key; only the server and client know the private key, but everyone can know the public key… who cares what they know.
    A client creates a unique HMAC (hash) representing it’s request to the server. It does this by combining the request data (arguments and values or XML/JSON or whatever it was planning on sending) and hashing the blob of request data along with the private key.
    The client then sends that HASH to the server, along with all the arguments and values it was going to send anyway.
    The server gets the request and re-generates it’s own unique HMAC (hash) based on the submitted values using the same methods the client used.
    The server then compares the two HMACs, if they are equal, then the server trusts the client, and runs the request.

**Explanation with an Example:**
(Suppose from android you are sending this request, since android apps are mostly sessionless they can't have cookies or any to remember which user has logged in. So. for this case, when a request is sent along with it user credentials also necessary.)

- Website for which request has to be made(in this case i'm using
  localhost): **localhost:8080/**
- URL REST request for an user X:
  **localhost:8080/REST/books/favorites** (assume response is in
  plain text separated by comma [ Harry Potter, Chandamama,
  Infinitethoughts, Twilight ] ).
- Since User X info has to be displayed request will be something like
  this:
  **localhost:8080/REST/username/Password/books/favorites -
  localhost:8080/REST/X/abc/books/favorites**

**here the problem is username and password can be sniffed as they are plain text..so, better encrypt them at client side and decrypt them at server side.**

**Now the actual problem arises, how does the server knows whether the request sent is sent by a valid client or not...**

- the solution for this is to generate hash of your URL request and add
  that hash at the end of the URL and then send the request to the
  server. (what we generally say is checksum).. generate a checksum
  using ur own or use java based hash generators like SHA1, MD5 etc
- Assume the hash generated for the URL request
  **localhost:8080/REST/encrypted-username/encrypted-Password/books/favorites**
  is some Hash string adasfsjimnom123123k. so, add this to your URL

**localhost:8080/REST/encrypted-username/encrypted-Password/books/favorites/adasfsjimnom123123k**

So, by this way you can secure the web service request. Only, when the generated checksum is valid, server gives the requested details.

**Use Curl tool as rest consuming client(instead of separate java code) for testing your services.**

[For Full Reference](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/)

Comment: your server could verify that the hash is correct because it had the private-key that was used by your client to generate the hash. How did you exchange a private-key between the client and server, to start with ?

Comment: This solution sounds ok. But public vs private key is not clear in the explanation. It seems that both use the same key. In some cases that shouldn't be a problem.